Making small acrylic parts
I'm wanting to make some small-ish parts from 4mm acrylic, however I'm a bit apprehensive due to the tapered design and the radii.

I have a selection of power tools in my arsenal, however a bandsaw isn't available. I do have a tablesaw, router, sander etc.
I think this is a 2 part question (sorry!):

Would I risk cracking with this design? I'm aware that I might need to re-think the outer radii due to the "holes should be at least 1.5x the thickness away from the edge" rule.
Can I use my sander to make the radii like you would typically see done with wood?


Probably better on some engineering stack.

what kind of home improvement is this

@Traveler it's a part to go on my temporary window pane that is also acrycli. A toggle to stop it falling outward.

@SolarMike ah, wil do :-)

@physicsboy Didn't you find anything from searching for "flyscreen swivel clip"? I suggest making the tapped hole first as that is the most likely thing to go wrong and make you have to start again.

For plastics I found that a diamond blade on a table saw works well for cutting.  It tends to cut by grinding more than a blade with teeth that will crack/catch the plastic.

Gotta 3D printer?

@AndrewMorton I didn't find too much, and definitely not at this size. Seems most screens like that are to sit in front of the window and not actually in the frame etc. I jut don't want the swivelly things stuck to the frame.

@Huesmann unfortunately not :-( Nor a glowforge

@physicsboy It isn't clear to me how temporary/permanent the arrangement is meant to be. Is it something that command strips would work for? Otherwise, all you can do is experiment with the acrylic. Bear in mind that hand tools won't melt it as quickly as power tools might.

Acrylic can be drilled, use a nail or a blunt drill bit,  you want to put heat into the acrylic by friction to soften it near the drill bit.
Sanding works well to shape external surfaces.
Tapping seems difficult, but maybe it could work if the tap is hot, but I think the threads would cause stress concentration.
Basically any process that causes lots of heat works well, but processes that cause mechanical stress and no, or little, heat tend to cause the acrylic to crack.

I think the latter part of your answer is the most important bit here.

A high-speed rotary tool or router should do well to rough-out the outline; I've used a hand-held rotary tool to cut out ~10 cm holes and boxes for an air-conditioner hose.
Cut the part oversize, because the high-speed cutter likely will melt the plastic as much as cut it, and then hand file and sand to shape. A power sander would likely melt the edges again.
That said, I find acrylic (Plexigalss,  polymethyl methacrylate) and polystyrene tend to craze. Consider polycarbonate (Lexan) if the part will be subject to stress - it's incredibly resilient, though more expensive.
